# Seperating duplicates in different codecs in foobar2000 library

Tags: audio, mp3, foobar2000, flac, music-management

I have a music library that is mostly flac. However every .flac album has an .mp3 duplicate in a folder named 'albumtitle [mp3]', since I copy the mp3 versions to my smartphone.

In foobar2000, however, I prefer to listen to the .flac files so I restrict to *.flac in the preferences.

The problem that I have is that there are a handful of albums that I *only* have in .mp3, and would like to see these in foobar2000.

So my question is is there a way to tell foobar2000 to show flac versions, unless there is no flac version in which case show .mp3 versions?

I suspect there is no way to do the above, in which case does anyone have a nice alternative way to deal with this problem?

I hope my question makes sense and thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Convert them up to FLAC? Waste of space, but simple.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I know. One alternative would be to store your MP3 albums separately from your FLAC albums.